# Setting the PyQGIS Maptool

Tags: pyqgis

I apologize if this question was already answered, but I found a lot of examples on how to set the QGIS maptool in a application from scratch, but not inside QGIS (in a plugin).

In the examples I found, the author creates a toolbar icon, an action and a custom QgsMapTool action.

What I want to do, is something (that I thought it was) more simple:
- I want to set the canvas maptool to be the QGIS native zoom in (QgsMapToolZoom); basically the same that happens, when the user clicks the zoom in icon on the QGIS toolbar;
Note that I don't want to zoom in like this:

```
canvas.zoomIn()
```

But I want to set the current mapTool to zoom in, and let the user zoom instead.

I implemented it as follows:

```
        canvas=self.eaf.iface.mapCanvas()

        zoomTool=QgsMapToolZoom(canvas, False)

        canvas.setMapTool(zoomTool)
```

However this fails. QGIS unsets the current maptool (lets say, for instance pan) and sets a void maptool (represented by an arrow cursor and no action)
I added this piece of code, after initializing the zoom tool:

```
        zoomTool=QgsMapToolZoom(canvas, False)

        act=zoomTool.action()
        print act
```

And found out that the action of the tool is empty (None).
I don't want to start an action, because I would like to use the native QGIS actions that are associated to the QGIS toolbar icons.
How can I access the native QGIS zoom action and force my maptool to use it?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get access to the native mpatool actions via several `iface.actionXXX()` methods which you can trigger. For your case this is

```
iface.actionZoomIn().trigger()
```

or

```
iface.actionZoomOut().trigger()
```

Comment: @Matthias Kuhn I followed your advice and got the same thing going for iface.actionAddFeature().trigger() in qgis 2.0. Have you had any experience, however, with this not working for qgis 2.4 as i have? If so, I've asked this question and am wondering if you have insight: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106994/qgis-2-4-plugin-changes-map-tool-canvas-click-behavior-from-2-0?noredirect=1#comment149576_106994